# How can i get the tag of the checkboxes after they are checked?

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I've tried this:

```
private int[] intCheckBox = {
        R.id.monCheck,
        R.id.tueCheck,
        R.id.wedCheck
};

private CheckBox[] realCheckBox = new CheckBox[intCheckBox.length];

private int i;
```

Then:

```
 for (i=0;i<intCheckBox.length;i++){
        realCheckBox[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(intCheckBox[i]);
        realCheckBox[i].setTag(i);
        realCheckBox[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(showFinal);
    }
```

}

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener showFinal = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String outPut2 = "";

        if (realCheckBox[i].isChecked()){
            outPut2 += realCheckBox[i].getTag();
            outPutText3.setText(outPut2);

        }
```

However, when i ran the app, there was an error shown after i had checked one of the boxes, and the error was:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

I know there is another way to get the tag or even the string by setting them one by one... Yet, i would like to use the array to show the tag in order to do the further coding that to get the int value of "whatIReallyWantToGet":

```
 java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, position);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, whatIReallyWantToGet);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String output = "";
        while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
            output += cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + ",";
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        }
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. I'm just a new learner from textbooks and online resources. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared, it seems to me that you are not resetting the value of the variable i.

That would explain why the exception says you are trying to access the index 3 of the array

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **length=3; index=3**